# How to confirm that image was taken with specific device?

Tags: java, android, image, exif

I want to write function in my android application that will confirm that picture was
 taken by specific mobile device.

Today I can tell, if the picture was taken by specific model. (like galaxy s3).

But,I want more than that. 
I would like to get from image EXIF unique id and compare it to the device unique id.

Thanks for help.

Comment: after some research i understand that "exif unique id" is unique for every photo (timestamp + camera serial encrypted) so i don't think it's a great start if you need to know if it's taken by this device. You could start to work on camera serial and timestamp and maybe a way to read it and decrypt it. What a great question which could let you search around internet for hours... My experience with Android Camera API is limited so i don't know if you can read serial number (if any?)

Comment: What happens if the EXIF data is re-written to 'fake' the information?

Comment: For my application, it doesn`t matter, I will not accept this image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using a long code. You can use a pre-ready Library for that.

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageFile);
```

This is the example code used by the Library, https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

It would give you the MetaData for the image. Which is also the content you want, Like the GeoLocation, CellularInformation, Resolution, Focus and all other data attached to the image.

A qoutation from the link

> It understands several formats of metadata, all of which may be present in a single image:    In addition it can decode values that are specific to particular camera manufacturers and models.

Then you can check for the details on that image and show or hide or what so ever you want to do with that image.

You can get the code from Google Code too: https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/

Good luck!

Comment: If i understand his question he already knows how to read it. He want to check if the photo has been done by the device which he uses

Comment: So this library would help him get the other data too. Like phone make and model, see the qoute in my post. Developer has made it clear that the code would crypt some of the Device info too. :) It would help OP to work with his project

Comment: Thanks for answering.  

How is this library different from:  
manufacturer = exifData.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);  
model = exifData.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);  

I need to get unique id from image, that will tell me, that it was taken by this exact device.